# How can I switch back and forth between globally installed Drush versions?

Tags: drush, composer

I installed Drush 8 using [`cgr`](https://github.com/consolidation/cgr) (which is a safer replacement for `composer global require`):

```bash
cgr drush/drush:8.x-dev --prefer-source
```

But now I also want to install Drush 9 for certain sites. Is there a way to switch between Drush 8 and 9 easily?

Comment: It's all about site local drush these days - installing 8 globally is fine, it will automatically switch to using the local site version when one is available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably know newer Drush versions have to be installed locally. Go ahead with installing Drush 10 (Drush 9 is EOL) for certain sites. The globally installed Drush acts as Drush Launcher and will find local Drush installs.

Comment: Really? You don't need the Drush Launcher at all anymore? Drush itself acts as a Drush Launcher? How cool is that?

Comment: OK, if you don't need Drush 8 anymore you probably shouldn't install the legacy version and use the much leaner Drush Launcher instead.

Comment: Ah okay, but if I have uncomposerized D7s laying around global Drush 8 is the way to go to act as a Launcher on the Composer projects. Nice!