# Is it possible to install Drush 9 without using Composer?

Tags: drush, composer

Is it somehow possible to install Drush 9 without using Composer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I switch back and forth between globally installed Drush versions?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299779/how-can-i-switch-back-and-forth-between-globally-installed-drush-versions)

Comment: In the end it would probably work you install it with Composer locally and then upload vendor to wherever you can't use Composer. Or simply commit vendor.

Answer (score 3):

No.

As it [says in the docs](https://docs.drush.org/en/9.x/install/):

> Drush 9 only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal 8 site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency.

If you don't know how to use composer, you need to learn now, because you'll have serious problems using Drupal without it.

Comment: It is _technically_ possible to do it. But in the same way it would be technically possible to fill a swimming pool with only a teaspoon. Not worth the effort when a hose is already available.